bar chart not resize
I got a problem trying to plot the larger version of this data (it has weeks till today) having all data in that plot space makes not legible the bars labels (3rd image as reference), I don't know what the problem is because it also plot a void figure with the size I gave. Pd. This was my best trial to make a combination of stacked and grouped chart, if someona has a better way to make it, please tell 
Chart to resize
Void figure
example of the data 3rd image
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Provided data
data = {
    'TYPE': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a'],
    'PRODUCT': ['Helium', 'Silver', 'Copper', 'Hidrogen', 'Helium', 'Silver', 'Silver'],
    'Amount': [62, 15, 70, 4, 3, 4, 25],
    'WEEK': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1]
}

# Create DataFrame
df_ini = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Plotting the bar chart grouped by week and showing all the products
df_pivot = df_ini.pivot_table(
    index=['WEEK','TYPE'],
    columns='PRODUCT',
    values='Amount',
    aggfunc='sum',
    fill_value=0
)

# Plotting the bar chart
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
ax = df_pivot.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)

# Custom x-axis labels
new_labels = [f'{week} / {type}' for week, type in df_pivot.index]
ax.set_xticklabels(new_labels,rotation=45,ha='right')

# Adding labels and title
plt.title('Claims by week')
plt.xlabel('Week')
plt.ylabel('Claims')
plt.legend(title='Product')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


Remove the below line from your code. It is creating one extra blank Figure.
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))


Also, have you tried using the code below? It should decrease the bar thickness.
ax = df_pivot.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, width=0.2)


Ok, now I know where the mistake was. So that was a fossilized mistakes, because I have always put figure settings before the plotting instead putting it inside the plot function. <3

for the grouping issue I found a similar question and the answer told us to use method .patches from axes object, in that way we can modify the coords of the columns. I was shocked with that function :0

Can you share the grouping answer elaborately? It might be the updated code.

fahim irfan, I just update as a comment the code that I used to plot the grouped by - stacked bar, hope you find it useful

well for that as petition of fahim the solution that I found to show a pseudo grouped-stacked bar was to use .patches method, its function is to show or in this case to change the coords of the objects of the plot. The con I found is that the plot only looks good if you make only 2 groups, because the x-axis labels do not change its position (IDK if you can add labeling coords, gonna find out). So the censored code is this
pivot_table = df_to_pivot.pivot_table(
    index=['week', 'column_to_group_by'],
    columns='column_to_stack',
    values='Value_to_show',
    aggfunc='sum',
    fill_value=0 #This fills the nan values from the pivot table
)

# Setting the plot
ax = pivot_table.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(16,6))

# Custom x-axis labels
new_labels= [f'{week}/{group_by}' for week, group_by in pivot_table.index]
ax.set_xticklabels(new_labels, rotation=45,ha='right')

# Placing labels


# Adding labels and title
plt.xlabel('X_Axis_label')
plt.ylabel('Y_Axis_label')
plt.title('Title')
ax.legend(title='Legend_Title',bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc='lower left', ncols=7, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.)
plt.tight_layout()
#plt.grid()

plt.savefig(f'{root_file_path}name.png', format='png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=300)

variable_to = 0 # This part of the code is the one that displace the columns ploted and makes them look like grouped by bars, important to know that no matter the quantity of the bar, it will always be plotted, so be carefull using this for loop as the grouping by technique
for i in range(len(ax.patches)):
    variable_to += 1
    if variable_to % 2 != 0:
        ax.patches[i].set_x(ax.patches[i].get_x()+0.125)
    else:
        ax.patches[i].set_x(ax.patches[i].get_x()-0.125)


# Show the plot
plt.show()

I hope you find it usefull, and help me improving the code <3
